# hover effects with dagre / dagre-d3 / d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dagre-d3, dagre

this is my first post, hopefully someone could help me out on this one...

the content you can see in the jsfiddle example is made with a tool i am working with.
All the definitions of nodes and edges (links) are generated by our tool ("VAR STATES = .." and "g.setEdge", etc..)
(the tooltips are not working here, just ignore)

in the selection "allnodes" (on mouseover) i just could select the current node (d3.select(this), but not the objects known as names in SELECTIT)

**what i want to achieve:**

1.) a "mouseover" effect like here: http://cs.brown.edu/people/jcmace/d3/graph.html?id=small.json

I could select the affect node names in the "mouseover" method:

```
    var selectit = g.neighbors(d);
```

-> API documentation of dagrejs/graphlib found here: https://github.com/dagrejs/graphlib/wiki/API-Reference

2.) a "mouseover" effect when selecting a link (including parent and children node)

the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kraab/n9mgo74j/32/

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

i found a solution myself, jsfiddle updated.
with the `.each` method you can iterate through all the selected elements, if the actual element `d` is found in the Array of neighbours `selectit` you know that you are now on the correct object and with  `d3.select(this)` you can change the actual object. The actual object you hover on is saved to `elemtosearch` and needs too be changed too...

https://jsfiddle.net/n9mgo74j/37/

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't perform very well, I think you are probably getting too many events

Comment: Thanks for your fiddle Klaus, was really helpful !